# Mapping text value via searchkick error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a really weird error from the indexing of my data by searchkick.
Basically I'm trying to add a custom mapping to specify one column as a text type and not keyword.

Here's the mapping I'm using (as the default one for summary would be keyword):

```
searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {
  candidates: {
    properties: { 
      summary:   {type: "text"},
     }
  } 
}
```

But when running reindex I have this error:

```
Searchkick::ImportError: 
{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse", "caused_by"=>
{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.KeywordFieldMapper$KeywordFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType on field summary"}} on item with id '123'
```

I tried a lot of things:

- Change analyzer
- Update searchkick and elasticsearch, and tried different versions
- Try exactly the same queries and mapping via Kibana console (where it actually does work, no problem indexing the same data as the mapping is complaining about)
- Look up the code behind mapping text type field

I really can't find why elasticsearch or searchkick does not want to index my data as text.

If you have any idea on what I can try It would be a huge help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share the code you use for mapping.

Comment: @Sajin I added the mapping :)

Comment: I think the issue is caused because you have created the index with keyword type and now you are trying to make it text. Take a look at this. It may be helpful. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings

Comment: @Sajin Thanks for your answer. So to be sure that it's not a mapping update, I deleted all the data and the mapping via Kibana console and try to index some data via searchkick. Still the same error. The mapping is set properly but the indexing fail right at the first item.